# Find value in nested JSON and trace backwards for values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

With the JSON structure below.

Let's say I know the chapter "number" and section "number".

What would be the best way search and trace backwards from what I have, to get the "number" of the title in **titles** and then the **division** "number" ?

Of course there would be a large amount of divisions/titles/chapters and sections.

```
[
  {
    "name":"Division",
    "number":1,
    "TITLES":[
      {
        "CHAPTERS":[
          {
            "name":"chapter2",
            "number":2,
            "SECTIONS":[
              {
                "name":"section3",
                "number":3
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "name":"title1",
        "number":1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code (assuming a is your array of Data)

```js
var b = [];
var chapternumber = 2;
var sectionnumber = 3;
a.forEach(function (division, divisionindex) {
  division.TITLES.forEach(function (title, titleindex) {
    title.CHAPTERS.forEach(function (chapter, chaptersindex) {
      chapter.SECTIONS.forEach(function (section, sectionsindex) {
        if(section.number === sectionnumber && chapter.number === chapternumber){
          b.push({title: title.number, division: division.number});
        }
      })
    })
  });
})
console.log(b);
```

Outputs an Array with the matching Title and Division number.